# Strange behaviour in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci

I wrote the following piece of code:

```
it :: Int -> Int
it n
    | n < 1     = error "Invalid entry."
    | n == 1    = 0
    | otherwise = 1 + it (n `quot` 2)
```

When I load it into GHCi, something weird happens. The first time I call the function `it`, it works fine and returns the expected results. However, the next time, I get the following crash:

```
λ: :t it
it :: Int -> Int
λ: it 2
1
λ: it 2

<interactive>:4:1:
    Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> t0' with actual type `Int'
    The function `it' is applied to one argument,
    but its type `Int' has none
    In the expression: it 2
    In an equation for `it': it = it 2
λ: :t it
it :: Int
λ: it
1
```

It seems that the type of `it` is being somehow modified after the first call. Things get even stranger when `it` is called multiple times from `main`, i.e. all the calls return the expected results, but in the end `()` is assigned as the type of `it`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let r1 = it 1
        r2 = it 2
        r3 = it 3
    print r1
    print r2
    print r3

λ: main
0
1
1
λ: :t it
it :: ()
```

I believe this is a bug related to the identifier `it` and GHCi internals, since renaming the function to something else (as `it'`) completely solves the problem. Besides that, the body of the function appears to have no influence; doing `let it = (+) 2` and evaluating it multiple times is also problematic.

Any insight would be appreciated. The output of `ghci --version` is "version 7.6.3".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bad luck in naming: `it` is the name GHCi automatically binds to the result of your previous evaluation, so that you can conveniently refer to it again. So your first use immediately rebinds it, shadowing your definition.

If `it` is defined in a module, you should still be able to refer to it reliably from GHCi with the module prefix, e.g. `Main.it`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm glad to know that this is just another instance of the "bug vs feature" dilemma. :-) I certainly see the usefulness of `it`, but I wonder if there is a better way this feature could be implemented in GHCi in order to avoid such confusion... Maybe using a special keyword, rather than a valid Haskell function identifier? Or at least warning the user when loading functions named with reserved GHCi names... Finally, are there any other special names in GHCi that I should be aware of?

Comment: @alexandrelucchesi I recall from way back that Hugs used `$$` instead, although that could be confused with an operator. I think GHCi uses an ordinary identifier because the feature is implemented as normal code, see [the manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#idp7106400). I'm not aware of any other special names, `:show bindings` doesn't list any more.